# How do I display my error message as a link in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a validation such that if model_name is not unique, it will display a html link to view the existing model_name row. Something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpdcm.png), however my current code displays the message like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvnSE.png). What do I have to change in my code?
Here's my code validation code:

```
'model_name.unique'=>'Model Already exists. <a href="'.route('view.models',[$request->model_name]).'">Go to page.</a>',
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Here's the error part of my form:

```
<input type="text" name="model_name" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Model Name">
                    @error('model_name')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                   </div>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you pass the error in your blade file?

Comment: @geertjanknapen Hi I added the part of the code in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That escaped character. You can know more about it [here](https://kunststube.net/escapism/) and [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data).

So to be quick, you can try:

```
<input type="text" name="model_name" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Model Name">
                @error('model_name')
                <span class="text-danger">{!! $message !!}</span>
                @enderror
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the error like this in your blade file:

```
@error ('model_name')
  <span class="text-danger">{!! $message !!}</span>
@enderror
```

That ensure the link is parsed correctly, right now it's being escaped.
[Check this for examples](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this code: ‌

```
<input type="text" name="model_name" 
class="form-control @error('model_name') is-invalid @enderror" 
id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Model Name">

@error('model_name')
    <span class="text-danger">{!! $message !!}</span>
@enderror
```

You can also add a: ‌is-invalid to the relevant field class if there is an error and style it.